# Xamarin Forms WCF Async Call void return on a String function

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, xamarin.forms

I am trying to call a simple Login function in WCF service from Xamarin Forms.

I have referenced the service with no problems.

I have defined the client object like this:

```
Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
```

My service function name is Login and returns a String. Here is the definition:

```
Public Function Login(ByVal wUser As String, ByVal wPassword As String) As String Implements IService1.Login
    Return String.Format("Test")
End Function
```

When I try to call that function from Xamarin Forms ServiceClient object I only have access to LoginAsync function instead of Login. Researching a bit I saw that I have to use await with async functions.

I tried that but then the line displays an error "Can't use await with void":

```
await client.LoginAsync("user", "password");
```

What I am doing wrong?

If I remove the await statement the WCF functions executes correctly and returns  the "Test" string, but I do not know how to retrieve that on Xamarin Forms.

How can I retrieve the string that the function is trying to return?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried "string value = await client.LoginAsync("user", "password");"

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but the error with await "cant't use await with void" is still there. I do not understand this because my function is of type string not void. If I remove await then the error is "Can not convert from void to string".

Comment: what is the signature of the LoginAsync method?  It may require a callback method rather than using async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution.

I needed to asign a listener function to LoginCompleted event.

```
  client.LoginCompleted += client_LoginCompleted;
  client.LoginAsync("user", "password");
```

And then I can get the result in the EventArgs of that function

```
 static void client_LoginCompleted(object sender, LoginCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var result = e.Result;
    }
```

Here is the link that helped me to understand how async call works in WCF and the three posible ways of getting the result.

http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com.es/2013/03/asynchronous-operations-in-wcf.html

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Definitely helped me, thank you, but why the Login method is not available, why only loginasync method we should access any idea?